# Running a public static void main test to draw an object.

Tags: java

```
public static void draw (Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) return;

    g.drawOval (x, y, width, height);
    draw (g, x, y, width/2, height/2);
    draw (g, x+width/2, y, width/2, height/2);
}
```

So on the code above i am trying to run a test but it keeps giving me errors. This is obviously a HW question where I think i have the code part down but believe it or not, we haven't really covered how to test the fictions properly. So I am trying:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    draw (g, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    //draw (null, 1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Any help will be appropriated. Thank you.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, have you declared `g` anywhere above your call to `Draw()`?

Comment: It wants to set a 'g' as local variable or if I do 'null' i get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at algs11.FileName.draw(FileName.java:110)
 at algs11.FileName.main(FileName.java:162)

Comment: You need to make a `Graphics` object to pass to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `swing`?
You will need a graphics object to draw on!

how about

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  JFrame f=new JFrame();            // create a window object in which to place a component
  f.add(new JLabel(){               // create a component within the window
    public void paint(Graphics g){  // override paint on this component to get a drawing area
      super.paint(g);               // call the default drawing command to draw background
      draw(g, 1,2,3,4);             // call your drawing routine
    }
  });
  f.pack();                         // make frame big enough for the label
  f.setVisible(true);               // show the frame, with its contents. 
  // Only after this is your routine actually called to do the drawing.
} // the main program now exits, but Java's event thread continues to run in the background, 
// drawing your object until the window is closed.
```

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, I am trying to go over your solution and trying to understand it now. All this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, it might be useful to first make a JFrame and add a panel to it, then override the JPanel's paint function to draw.

The JFrame creates a Frame to hold info in. Then add the panel so you have a surface to draw on.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();     
  frame.add(new JPanel()
  {
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      super.paint(g);
      drawLine(g, 10,10,100,100);
    }
  });
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

So what you are effectively doing:

1. Make a window(JFrame)
2. Add a surface to draw on(JPanel)
3. Override the Panels paint function, so you can enter your own logic for drawing stuff
4. Set the window(JFrame) to visible so you can see what you are doing

I hope this clears things up a bit :)

Comment: You are welcome. An up vote would be nice, will allow me to use the comments :)