# bigger JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, 2d, shapes

I'm working on a program that presents the results as simple 2D shapes. I used the solution from this question: [Running a public static void main test to draw an object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062272/running-a-public-static-void-main-test-to-draw-an-object) I was wondering if I could make the new window size bigger. Because it doesn't have enough space for all shapes.
Currently, the results are like this:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZRPl.png)

By the way, my code is this:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.add(new JLabel(){
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawLine(50, 50, r12, 50);
        g.drawLine(50, r13, r12, r13);
        g.drawLine(50, 50, 50, r13);
        g.drawLine(r12, 50, r12, r13);  
     }       
});
```

Comment: 1) Don't extend a JLabel for custom painting. Instead extend JPanel. 2) Don't override paint(). Instead override `paintComponent(...)`. 3) implement the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom painting class. See: [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.